# What's the fast way to navigate to MAC OSX "Finder"?

Tags: osx, files

On Mac OSX, I'm editing a file in an Emacs buffer.  I need to conveniently open the directory containing this file in the MAC OSX Finder.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: From SO: [in Emacs, how to show current file in Finder?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20510333/1219634)

Comment: It's really unfortunate that `reveal-in-finder` uses the name `finder` without qualification (in the library name and in the code). **`finder.el`** is a *longstanding, standard Emacs library*, and its commands, functions and variables use the name `finder` to mean something quite different from the "MAC OS X Finder". I wish that the `reveal-in-finder` maintainer would consider using a name and name component such as `macosx-finder` or `osx-finder`, instead of just `finder`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My way wasn't shown in the other thread: `M-! open . RET`.

`open` is a general OS X command which will cause the system to open a file or directory in the default application.  `.` is the current directory.

I don't do this very often, so I find it faster to type the above incantation than to write a function and map it somewhere.  `M-x open-in-finder` would take more characters than above.